# Why do I get special characters when getting the source code of a website? c++

Tags: c++, web-scraping, special-characters

I am trying to get the source code of Barack Obama's Wikipedia page and save it to a file.

Everything works well until I open the file and see some weird characters in it:

[image]

As you can see, `EOT1024` appears in the file, but it does not appear in the website's actual source code, which I checked using Google Chrome. I would like to know why this is happening, and how I can stop it from happening.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <fstream>
int main(){
    std::string textLink = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama";
    std::ofstream file;
    HINTERNET hInternet, hFile;
    char buf[1024];
    DWORD bytes_read;
    int finished = 0;
    bool e=false;
    std::string waste;

        file.open("data.txt",std::ios::out);
        hInternet = InternetOpenW(L"Whatever", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
        if (hInternet == NULL) {
            printf("InternetOpen failed\n");
        }
        hFile = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, textLink.c_str(), NULL, 0L, 0, 0);
        if (hFile == NULL) {
            printf("InternetOpenUrl failed\n");
        }
        while (!finished) {
            if (InternetReadFile(hFile, buf, sizeof(buf), &bytes_read)) {
                if (bytes_read > 0) {
                    file  << bytes_read << buf;
                }
                else {
                    finished = 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                printf("InternetReadFile failed\n");
                finished = 1;
            }
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
        InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        file.close();
}
```

I have the text file as I view it in Notepad++ right here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ty-a1o29RWSQiO1zTLym6XH4dJvUjpTO

I don't understand why I would get those characters in the `data.txt` file that I write to.

**NOTE:** occasionally, instead of seeing `EOT1024`, I even get `EOT21`, `EOT1016`, and other seemingly random characters.

Comment: Your encoding is?

Comment: It is UTF-8. Does that have anything to do with this problem?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: Tagging this question with C++ is misleading

Comment: On a side note, consider WinHTTP instead of old fashioned WinInet.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Why's that? It's a C++ program, and the bug was [partially] in the usage of a C++ feature.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Cause while STL streams and strings are being used (and even a C++ version of `main`), it's more of a C question. It's much like using C++ style comments in C programs. That's just my opinion and I can see why other people may think otherwise.

Comment: WinHHTP is worse than WinInet and not properly documented.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb Since standard streams and strings and a C++ main are being used, this is clearly a C++ question not a C question. Simple as that!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are entitled to that opinion, I however, do not share it.

Comment: @MosheGottlieb It's not an opinion; it is a fact. Nothing about this question is C. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're literally writing the integer `bytes_read` to the file:

```
file  << bytes_read << buf;
```

There's your "1024" (on the occasions that 1024 bytes were read).

Don't do that.

Furthermore, it looks like you're assuming `buf` is null-terminated. Instead, stream the first `bytes_read` of `buf`; that's why you have that integer.

So:

```
file.write(&buf[0], bytes_read);
```

Consult [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetreadfile):

> A normal read retrieves the specified dwNumberOfBytesToRead for each call to InternetReadFile until the end of the file is reached. To ensure all data is retrieved, an application must continue to call the InternetReadFile function until the function returns TRUE and the lpdwNumberOfBytesRead parameter equals zero.